# A regular expression in C# to parse BBCode-style tags

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that matches some tags surrounded with square brackets. Nothing fancy, I just need it to match the tags. Like these:

```
[quote]  
[/quote]  
[b]  
[url]
```

etc

I don't need it to worry about closing tags or anything. I just want to get a collection of all tags within a text. My regular expression knowledge is more than limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't worried about matching the end or nesting or any of those silly complications, this will match and capture those tags:

```
(\[[^\]]*\])
```

Comment: Perfect, that is all I needed. Not worried about the silly complications :) Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there is a problem. Let me get a screen shot of the result in expresso.

Comment: This is probably improved either with the class `[^\]]` or the lazy operator: `(\[[^\]]*\])` or `(\[.*?\])`

Comment: Got it. That's that whole nesting thing I was talking about :) I'll edit this answer to use Paul's example which handles that case

Comment: Thank you Ashelvey. I will accept in a few minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should work provided you don't care about the makeup of the text that falls within the square brackets: `\[[^\]]+\]`. If you want to limit to alphanumeric characters, `\[/?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]` will work. Or if you want just alphabetical characters, then remove the 0-9 from the character set.

Answer (score 1):

@ashelvey: That expression is greedy and will match too much. `(\[.*?\])` would be a reluctant version of the same expression.

If you only want to match the tags inside, you can use `(?<=\[).+?(?=\])`, using lookbehind and lookahead.

Comment: Also, if you want to ignore closing tags:
`(?<=\[)[^/]+?(?=\])`